# CGFloat and NSTimeInterval "Cannot assigned a value of type Float to a value of type Int"

Tags: ios, swift

I keep getting `Cannot assigned a value of type Float to a value of type Int"` on the `touchVelocityX = xFloat / timeFloat` even though I'm converting everything to floats.

```
    let lastTouchX = locationOfLastTouch.x
    let lastTouchY = locationOfLastTouch.y
    let currentTouchX = touchLocation.x
    let currentTouchY = touchLocation.y

    let xDistance = currentTouchX - lastTouchX
    let yDistance = currentTouchY - lastTouchY

    let xFloat = Float(xDistance)
    let yFloat = Float(yDistance)

    let timeSinceLastTouch = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(timeOfLastTouch)
    let timeFloat : Float = Float(timeSinceLastTouch)

    touchVelocityX = xFloat / timeFloat
    touchVelocityY = yFloat / timeSinceLastTouch
    timeOfLastTouch = NSDate()
    locationOfLastTouch = touchLocation
```

Comment: Is touchVelocityX an Int?

Comment: Note: Float and CGFloat are not the same type. Converting it to Float makes no sense

Comment: touchVelocityX was a float!!! Thank you so much problem solved